# phantomjs with Mac 10.15.7, valid element always returning empty string for getText()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I've got phamtomjs with Mac OS 10.15.7 and launching a website ( https://www.rupeevest.com/Mutual-Fund-Holdings/100477 )

In debug mode, I could see page content with `driver.getPageSource( )` with values which I want to verify but when I do

`((PhantomJSDriver) driver).findElementById("n_o_f").getText()` this always returns empty string " "

Is this bug with PhantomJS and MAC OS ?

PhantomJS has been stopped development in 2017 itself, is there a better alternative for headless browser ?

Comment: did you put some wait before that ? Can you try the same with chrome browser ?

Comment: It was bug with PhantomJS as same script worked fine with Chrome headless browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is recommended to use headless `ChromeDriver` rather that `PhantomJS` .
AFAIK it is more stable, continuously supported and much, much widely used platform.
Actually it's the regular, commonly used `ChromeDriver` just with `headless` parameter set `On`.
As about your specific problem I guess you should use `ExpectedConditions`, wait for visibility of that element and only after that get it's text.
Something like this:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("n_o_f")));
String yourText = driver.findElementById("n_o_f").getText();
```